# How to pass ID parameter for GET method without it being directly in the uri

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

For my school project I'm trying to build an API that allows students to basically CRUD school applications. API is divided into two modules, first one uses IDs directly in uris to access the data like in example below:

```
    @GetMapping("/students/{id}/applications")
public ResponseEntity<List> getStudentApplications(@PathVariable Long id){
    Optional<Student> studentById = studentRepo.findById(id);
    if(studentById.isPresent()){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(studentById.get().getApplications(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
```

And the second module consumes previous API while not using variables like studentID in uri, because students wont be able to browse other's applications so why include them:

```
    @GetMapping("/my-applications")
public ResponseEntity<List> getApplications(){
    return restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8081/students/{id}/applications", List.class, 1L);
}
```

My question is how can I pass the id variable to the restTemplate, without it being explicitly in the uri. Example above is obviously hardcoded for the id to be 1

Comment: maybe pass as query string ?

Comment: by not using get and instead using post, and the supply the data through the body, as you are posting data to the server.